# How can I use a MySQL stored procedure to count and sort a pipe-delimited field?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to create a stored procedure that will return the total count for each unique value encountered in a pipe-delimited field, roughly in the format in figure 2. Fortunately, the values will only ever be "value1", "value2", or "value3" if that makes things any simpler. I had originally planned to output the data and sort it in PHP by exploding the data and looping through for string matches, but there are extraordinary circumstances that require me to use a stored procedure and I've not used stored procedures before.

The data I'm interpreting is in the format shown below, where the 'valuelist' field is a pipe-delimited field containing many values. I need to find out how many times the values occurred each for a given date.

(figure 1 below) What the data looks like in the database.

```
id, date, valuelist
1, 2017-01-01, value1|value2|value3
2, 2017-01-01, value1|value2
3, 2017-01-01, value1
```

So a query of `select date, valuelist from db.table where id = 1;` will return `2017-01-01, value1|value2|value3`.

(figure 2 below) Desired count output representing how many times each value occurred on a specific date. For example, using the data from figure 1, if we ask about 2017-01-01, the output should look something like this.

```
value1: 3
value2: 2
value3: 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please read about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to write effective questions. Always be specific and make your best effort before asking. In this case, you should add your PHP

Comment: @NetBlues do you have a real sample value to your valuelist?

Comment: I edited your question because when you refer to a figure is so confusing I rename it as Results. But you rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are converting `3|2|1` to separate rows of `3`, `2`, `1`; MySQL (or pretty much any SQL-based RDBMS) does not lend itself well to that kind of output.

Without going into actual procedure code, in a procedure you could:

1. Store value in a local variable
2. Use a more general purpose stored function *(should be easy to find one around here)* to "split" the string on your delimiter `|`; or "loop" through your string using a "get n-th" function to split it iteratively.
3. Store values into a temp table
4. Use a SELECT on the temp table as your procedure's resultset.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

**Detailed as given sample data:**

```
SELECT  date,fval as allValue,count(fval) as ValueCount from
(select date,fval from
(select date,SUBSTRING_INDEX(rplace, ' ', 1)fval,SUBSTRING_INDEX(MID(rplace,8,LENGTH(rplace)), ' ', 1)sval,SUBSTRING_INDEX(MID(rplace,15,LENGTH(rplace)), ' ', 1)tval from
(select id,  date, valuelist,REPLACE(valuelist,'|',' ') as rplace from
(select 1 as id, '2017-01-01' as date, 'value1|value2|value3' as valuelist union all
select 2, '2017-01-01', 'value1|value2' union all
select 3, '2017-01-01', 'value1') as a)as a) as a

union all

select date,sval from
(select date,SUBSTRING_INDEX(rplace, ' ', 1)fval,SUBSTRING_INDEX(MID(rplace,8,LENGTH(rplace)), ' ', 1)sval,SUBSTRING_INDEX(MID(rplace,15,LENGTH(rplace)), ' ', 1)tval from
(select id,  date, valuelist,REPLACE(valuelist,'|',' ') as rplace from
(select 1 as id, '2017-01-01' as date, 'value1|value2|value3' as valuelist union all
select 2, '2017-01-01', 'value1|value2' union all
select 3, '2017-01-01', 'value1') as a)as a) as a

UNION all


select date,tval from
(select date,SUBSTRING_INDEX(rplace, ' ', 1)fval,SUBSTRING_INDEX(MID(rplace,8,LENGTH(rplace)), ' ', 1)sval,SUBSTRING_INDEX(MID(rplace,15,LENGTH(rplace)), ' ', 1)tval from
(select id,  date, valuelist,REPLACE(valuelist,'|',' ') as rplace from
(select 1 as id, '2017-01-01' as date, 'value1|value2|value3' as valuelist union all
select 2, '2017-01-01', 'value1|value2' union all
select 3, '2017-01-01', 'value1') as a)as a) as a) as a
where fval !='' GROUP BY fval,date
```

**final Query:**

```
SELECT  date,fval as allValue,count(fval) as ValueCount from
(select date,fval from
(select date,SUBSTRING_INDEX(rplace, ' ', 1)fval,SUBSTRING_INDEX(MID(rplace,8,LENGTH(rplace)), ' ', 1)sval,SUBSTRING_INDEX(MID(rplace,15,LENGTH(rplace)), ' ', 1)tval from
(select id,  date, valuelist,REPLACE(valuelist,'|',' ') as rplace from
(select * from yourTable) as a)as a) as a

union all

select date,sval from
(select date,SUBSTRING_INDEX(rplace, ' ', 1)fval,SUBSTRING_INDEX(MID(rplace,8,LENGTH(rplace)), ' ', 1)sval,SUBSTRING_INDEX(MID(rplace,15,LENGTH(rplace)), ' ', 1)tval from
(select id,  date, valuelist,REPLACE(valuelist,'|',' ') as rplace from
(select * from yourTable as a)as a) as a

UNION all


select date,tval from
(select date,SUBSTRING_INDEX(rplace, ' ', 1)fval,SUBSTRING_INDEX(MID(rplace,8,LENGTH(rplace)), ' ', 1)sval,SUBSTRING_INDEX(MID(rplace,15,LENGTH(rplace)), ' ', 1)tval from
(select id,  date, valuelist,REPLACE(valuelist,'|',' ') as rplace from
(select * from yourTable) as a)as a) as a) as a
where fval !='' GROUP BY fval,date
```

**Result:**

```
2017-01-01  value1  3
2017-01-01  value2  2
2017-01-01  value3  1
```

Comment: just do create procedure if you want.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look. This appears to only work when the values are literally 6 characters in length. However, the true values in the live fields could range between 1 and 16 characters.